# What are the official resources for the Java EE APIs spec?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, java-ee-6

I know a few official sources like the java Java EE 6 tutorial.

But I was wondering, which one are the official sources for properly learning the spec of every API and any other resource related to the Java EE environment? Which resources ppl use to keep track of future versions without being actively participating of any container or spec development?

I hope this question is specific enough by suggesting only official links.

EDIT:
About https://java.net/projects/javaee-spec/pages/Home. It has a lot of links for several document versions and optional content. I wanted just one single resource for each API, a complete version. Let's take for example the annotated ECMAScript 5 spec (http://es5.github.io/).
Assuming the links are permanent it would be very nice to point out the complete documents for the APIs from Java EE 6.

Comment: J2EE dropped that name since Java EE 1.5 or just Java EE 5. The official resource to learn is, as you said, the [Java EE 6 Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/) Apart of that, you can search on the net for info like CDI, EJB, JPA, JMS, etc.

Comment: The "2" in "J2EE" referred to version 2 of the spec.  It's 1999 vintage, announced at JavaOne that June.  Time to drop the two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java EE 6 APIs are available at:

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/

These can be downloaded from:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-eedocs-419425.html#java_ee_6u1_docs-JPR

Answer (score 1):

https://java.net/projects/javaee-spec/pages/Home

But not really sure why you couldn't google that.

Comment: That site has a lot of downloads for candidates, optional docs, etc. I want links for only the latest documents of each module without wasting time reading useless documents.

Comment: It has that and also links to the latest version of all of the specs.

Comment: Ok, but the question is specific :D